# Taking more time to load the spring-*.xsd files from classpath with no internet

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

Initially i had my header for appcontext.xml as below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">
```

This doesnt work if there is no internet connection. Hence changed the above xsi:schemaLocation as below

```
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   classpath:/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd"
```

The above approach takes a long time to load the xsd files and run the application.

Is there any other approach to minimise the time taken to load.I see that classpath:/.. is the only option to load xsd when there is no internet connection. Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

More information about `schemaLocation` is available here:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_schemaLocation
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#schemaLocation

If you use the Spring IDE installed in Eclipse, the IDE already has its own copy of the XSDs required by the `xmlns`s that you provided. Therefore, it does not need to look it up via the URL provided in the `schemaLocation`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Am running my application in a unix system via command prompt. So i need to have this schemaLocation provided.

Comment: The problem am facing is it is taking more time to load especially the xsd files even if i place them physically in the same folder as my appContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to change the schema location to refer to classpath to make it work; Spring is *supposed* to have its own copy of the schema files embedded in its jar files, and is *supposed* to use those in preference of connecting to the  internet for them.  However, I note that you've specified exact schema versions in the URLs to them, and my understanding is that Spring will only check for the versioned schemas that *exactly match the version of spring in use*.  In this case, if you weren't using Spring 3.1.x, it wouldn't use its own internal version and would attempt to download it instead.  Switch to the schema locations that *don't* have version numbers (which are backwards compatible) and it should use its internal cache.